# Can Python Beautiful-soup web scraper parse entire web contents

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to ask whether through Beautiful SOUP parser one can scrape through all the webpages in a single go without by just providing the url homepage and sublinks automatically parsed.

Comment: It definitely can. You need to look for href values on each page(be careful with externel urls). There's a great course at Udacity that'll teach you how to build a web crawler using Beautiful Soup(Intro to Computer Science). Personally I like lxml.html for that.

Answer (score 0):

No, this doesn't happen automatically.

You can use find_all to find the hrefs, then ignore the ones that go to external websites.  I haven't tested this but it's the general idea:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests

visited = set()
to_visit = set(['foo.com/'])

while to_visit:

    target = to_visit.pop()
    visited.insert(target)
    html = requests.get(target).text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        href = a['href']
        full_url = target + href
        if full_url not in visited and not href.starts_with('http'):
            to_visit.insert(full_url)
```